# Get rows of table that have X amount of rows with certain value in joined table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with finding a correct SQL(oracle) Query(probably a nooby problem):

I have this table which is already a joined table

```
---------------------
|PersonID | NumberA  | Group |
-------------------------
| 1 | 111      | 02    |
-------------------------
| 2 | 222      | 02    |
-------------------------
| 3 | 467      | 02    |
-------------------------
| 1 | 122      | 01    |
-------------------------
| 5 | 048      | 01    |
-------------------------
| 5 | 491      | 01    |
```

Now I want to get all persons that have at least one row with value '02' in group column AND at least one row with value '01' in group column.

I can't come up with a solution how to query this correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` and `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` together:

```
SELECT "PersonID"
FROM your_table
WHERE "Group" IN ('01', '02')
GROUP BY "PersonID"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Group") = 2
```

If you are looking for exactly *x amount of rows with certain value* then change the having clause to something like:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN "Group" = '01' THEN 1 END) = 2
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN "Group" = '02' THEN 1 END) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you that looks great. In this case you are testing if group 01 has 2 rows and group 02 has 3 rows right?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Group") = 2` will check if **both** values from the where clause are present **at least 1 time**. `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END) = 2 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END) = 3` checks the **exact number of time** they are present.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `group by` and `having`:

```
select personID
from t
where groupId in ('01', '02')
group by personID
having min(groupId) = '01' and max(groupId) = '02';
```

Comment: Thank you! What exactly does the `having min(groupId) = '01' and max(groupId) = '02'` do ?

Comment: @pokeahontas . . . It checks that both values are assigned to the person.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the `JOINED` table result as single table, then you can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where group ('01', '02') and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.personid = t.personid and t1.group <> t.group);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT p1.personID from person p1,person p2 where p1.personID=p2.personID and p1.group_id<>p2.group_id
```